# Bootstrap formatting columns align issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Working html code: UPDATED

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" role="search">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label col-md-6" for="inputEmail">Employee Name:</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="inputEmail" type="email" value="John Edward Jr.">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="form-control btn btn-info">Hello world</button>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label col-md-6" for="inputEmail">My Owning Location:</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="inputEmail" type="email" value="abc123 234sd 343 scott 359 to-34-23-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I format my lable/input field align? below is html along with screen shots how it renders after I run the page:

what I want the output to be is:

> ```
>         Employee Name:         XXXXXXXXXXXXX
>    My Owning Location:         XXXXXXXXXXXXX
>          Manager Name:         XXXXXXXXXXXXX
> ```

```
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="navbar-form form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" role="search" style="padding:0">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 10px;">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-6" for="inputEmail">Employee Name:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="inputEmail" type="email" value="John Edward Jr.">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 10px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-6" for="inputEmail">My Owning Location:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="inputEmail" type="email" value="abc123 234sd 343 scott 359 to-34-23-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: if you remove the navbar-form class you will get something similar to what you want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this for you and created a [codepen editor](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMEqPN?editors=1010) for this.

The code will look lke,

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" role="search">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label col-md-6" for="inputEmail">Employee Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="inputEmail" type="email" value="John Edward Jr.">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label col-md-6" for="inputEmail">My Owning Location:</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="inputEmail" type="email" value="abc123 234sd 343 scott 359 to-34-23-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I've done is wrap your form group elements into `row` classes which makes children appear in a row, and for the `form-group` classed element I've set it to `col-md-12` which does make it full width of the grid.

I've also removed `navbar-form` class from your `form` element

I've heard my colleague (front-end guy) saying to use `row` and child elements of them as grid columns as a standard, i don't know the validity of that statement, but it works for real! :)

And a note, do not use inline styles which makes things lot worse and untraceable while looking at the code itself.

Comment: Hi @kisanme, can you try to run you code in jsfiddle if you can get the same result as you run it in codepen. Seem jsfiddle can't handle bootstrap codes properly.

Comment: if I remove `navbar-form` then my in-line is not working, meaning that I have a input field and next to that i have a button and if i keep the `navbar-form` the button is next to the input field which is great but the width of the input field is not lesser then what i wanted arhggg....any idea?

Comment: @aldrien.h It works fine in JSFiddle as well, there we should link the bootstrap and font awesome libraries in the resources section available in the sidebar. And note the preview section in JSFiddle is smaller, which means it is applying the styles according to the size as this uses bootstrap, you can see the exact output as in CodePen if you increase the preview size. Hope that helps

Comment: @AbuHamzah If you want your button besides the input element, then i personally would use [this method](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMEqPN?editors=1000) rather than adding `navbar-form` which seems complicating the case (which seems like restricting the input width to a fixed one, overriding the grid column classes)

Answer (score 1):

I added the corresponding row-fluid to reset the grid for the label and input boxes.
https://jsfiddle.net/gyod/7mgtfk3k/4/ Here is one example.

```
<form class="container row-fluid navbar-form form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" role="search" style="padding:0">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 10px;">

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="inputEmail">Employee Name:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="inputEmail" type="email" value="John Edward Jr.">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 10px;">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="inputEmail">My Owning Location:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="inputEmail" type="email" value="abc123 234sd 343 scott 359 to-34-23-3">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: still the same its not align as per the jsfiddle you posted

Comment: Just remove the form-group.  Updated Fiddle

Comment: Hopefully this helps!

Comment: how do i get the space between input even though i have `style="margin: 10px;"`

Comment: 1+ How do increase the width of an input field? i can use `style="width...` but bootstrap should automatically increase the width based on the col-xs-9 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the label tag inside div class="col-xs-6". Then you can get a horizontal aligned elements of each div.

If you want to make it properly align, you can set default width for the label and use bootstrap built-in class for alignment.